# In Silverstripe 4, a standard "Add" button of a GridField does nothing

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm trying to use a GridField component for the first time.
I've added an 'Add' button using GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor as followings:

```
class AdvertisersPage extends Page
{
    //...

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $advertiserAccounts = AdvertiserAccount::get();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Advertisers',
            $gridField = new GridField(
                'Advertisers',
                'All advertisers',
                $this->Advertisers(),
                GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
            )
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

But the button doesn't do anything besides changing the URL in the browser from

> admin/pages/edit/show/7

to

> admin/pages/edit/EditForm/7/field/Advertisers/item/new

Here is the related DataObject class:

```
class AdvertiserAccount extends DataObject
{
    //...

    private static $has_one = [
        'AdvertisersPage' => AdvertisersPage::class,
    ];

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('contactNumber'),
            TextField::create('nickname')
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

I need your advice on what should I look at to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is an extremely strange bug.

I've made some experiments and renamed the related classes. I found that the problem only appears when first GridField constructor parameter *name* is one of the followings: 'Adv', 'Advert', 'Advertise', 'Advertiser' and 'Advertisers'. In the project, I haven't got any classes with such names. Full-text search through all the project's files hasn't gave any results.

So, I've solved the problem just by renaming the parameter, but what was that?